# Drawing a grid of squares in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, draw

1) I want to draw a grid of squares (AspectRatio -> 1.0). The dimension of the grid is 200*150. 2) I want the first 8760 squares (from left to right, top to bottom) in the grid to be gray. Thanks.

*For 1), I don't know where to put the ratio; for 2) I have an ugly solution and am looking forward an elegant one.*

The code I have now:

```
Grid[Table["", {200}, {150}], 
 Background -> {None, 
   None, {{{1, 58}, {1, 150}} -> Gray, {{59, 59}, {1, 75}} -> Gray}}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

Comment: Grid does not have an `AspectRatio` option. Instead you can use the option `ItemSize`. If you add `ItemSize -> {.75, 1}` to your code you get squarish cells.

Comment: @kguler Thanks! It works. Could you put your solution as an answer? And, is 0.75 an experimental result?

Comment: Yes, 0.75 is found by trial and error; after trying `{1,1}` and seeing that it does not work. Your code looks ok. Don't see an obviously more elegant alternative.

Comment: Do you need a `Grid` object, or would a bitmap or `Graphics` object also be suitable?  What is your use?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Eventually, I need an image object, and I would export it to a ".eps" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid does not have an `AspectRatio` option. Instead you can use the option `ItemSize`. If you add `ItemSize -> {.75, 1}` to your code you get squarish cells.

Comment: On version 7 I get square "cells" with `ItemSize -> {0.5, 1}` -- clearly this is not inter-system reliable.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think it also has to do with monitor display settings- my circles becomes ellipses when I move from one external monitor to another.